# Java Path compression

Tags: java, path, compression

I have to create a method find that would use a local Set to collect the objects and the root. Then, I would compress the object e (in the parameter) and have the roost as its parent. Then, I would return the reference to the root. I can use the Graph, Map, and set class since it was imported. But, how can I call the parent of the root? would I just put 
`mapParent.get(e)`?

EDIT 
The method's function is to have the node point to the root, and I want to use a Set to put together all the objects between the parameter and the object's root. Then, I would use path compression. Then, I have to return the reference to the object. So, I was wondering how I would call the parent for the object to somehow refer to the parent. So here is what I got:

```
public T find (T obj){
    //Set<E> s = new HashSet<E>(sizeOfRoot.size()); // i don't know how I would use the set yet
      T p = null;
      if (map.get(obj).equals(obj)) // I was trying to get the parent of e
          return obj; 
      else{
          p = find(map.get(obj)); // recursively call the method to path compress
      }

    return p; // return the reference to the node
  }
```

Can you please help steer me in the right direction?

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is incomprehensible. Can you describe more clearly what you're trying to achieve and what specific issue are you facing? Perhaps provide an example?

Comment: Does it sound like a homework assignment to anyone else?

Comment: Are you trying to represent a directory structure in standard Java collections?

Comment: The only path compression algorithm that I know of deals with disjoint-set forests (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure). If that's what you're trying to work with (your description is still rather unclear), your Node class should contain a reference to its parent; using map for this purpose is somewhat strange (not to mention slow).

Comment: If that's where you're keeping your node associations then yes. Isn't `T` in the above code your node class, though? Or is that a generic placeholder for node value?

Comment: yes its a generic placeholder, so I would also have to add in the object into the set as well? And, yes its a directory structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way is to store parent with each node. If you can't do it for whatever reason then you should use a Map, rather than Set.

Somewhere in your code you would fill this map, by calling

```
mapParents.put(obj, parent)
```

Then later you can retrieve parent by calling

```
parent=mapParents.get(obj)
```

All this, assuming I understand your requirements correctly.